# Best way to test JSONP Request on localhost Dev Box

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I don't have a testing server I can deploy on easily and i'd like to test some jsonp requests. Whats the best way to do this if i'm just deploying from eclipse on a dev box? Is it considered a cross site request if I deploy 2 instances of a server in eclipse, on separate ports? Is there some way to fake it and test locally within the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP doesn't require 2 hosts, it just supports it. So wether your JSONP response is coming from a remote server or the same server, it works pretty much the same.

Comment: Ok so there is nothing tricky I might neglect to include while testing that will destroy the request if it were coming from a remote site instead? Thats my main concern...

Comment: It depends on how you are making the JSONP requests I guess. jQuery for instance, will change it's strategy based on whether the URL being requested is a different Origin or not, switching between regular AJAX  and JSONP invisibly for you. In that case it may make a difference. But if using JSONP directly, it doesn't much matter where the response comes from.

Answer (score 1):

As far as two domains dont match up you should be fine to test it as a cross site jsonp call .

The term "origin" is defined using the domain name, application layer protocol, and (in most browsers) port number of the HTML document running the script. Two resources are considered to be of the same origin if and only if all these values are exactly the same.

Comment: So localhost:8080 and localhost:8090 are considered different domains?

Comment: Since the port are different the same origin policy would apply and block your XHR call.

Comment: @ryandlf Yes, different ports are considered a different "Origin" by the browser.